# Can't add intermediate cert to ca-certificates.crt via /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

Tags: encryption, ssl, certificates

On Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, I'm attempting to add an intermediate cert to the system's store of trusted CA certs. I installed the .crt file in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates, then ran update-ca-certificates. The symlink was created from /etc/ssl/certs to the .crt. However, the cert was not included into /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.

[Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html) for update-ca-certificates says:

> update-ca-certificates  is  a  program  that  updates   the   directory
>   /etc/ssl/certs to hold SSL certificates and generates certificates.crt,
>   a concatenated single-file list of certificates.
>
> It reads the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf. Each line gives a pathname
>   of  a  CA  certificate  under /usr/share/ca-certificates that should be
>   trusted.  Lines that begin with "#" are comment lines and thus ignored.
>   Lines  that  begin with "!" are deselected, causing the deactivation of
>   the CA certificate in question.
>
> Furthermore   all   certificates   found   below   /usr/local/share/ca-
>   certificates are also included as implicitly trusted.

I was able to get the cert into ca-certificates.crt by editing the /etc/ca-certificates.conf file and giving the path to the cert, then running update-ca-certificates.  So my question is: is the man page wrong and does the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates method not work?  Or did I miss a trick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Did you install the certificate in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` with suffix `.crt`? This is the part in the update-ca-certificates script, which adds certs from `LOCALCERTSDIR`:

```
if [ -d "$LOCALCERTSDIR" ]
then
  find -L "$LOCALCERTSDIR" -type f -name '*.crt' | sort | while read crt
  do
    add "$crt"
  done
fi
```

You might want to check if `LOCALCERTSDIR` is set to the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` directory. After running update-ca-certificates I got a link from `/etc/ssl/certs/xyz.pem` to `$LOCALCERTSDIR/xyz.crt` and its content has been added to the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. Hope this helps!